# hide an inner div if an outer div is resized smaller than 240px

Tags: jquery, show-hide

i am trying to hide an inner div (containing a sentence), when an outer div is resized with a toggle width button.

e.g. outer div starts off at 300px wide, when a button is clicked it shrinks to 200px wide.

If the outer div is resized to less than 240px (for example), then the inner div is hidden altogether. Then if button toggled, then inner dic reappears.

Existing code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfHZV/509/

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#toggle-button').click( function() {
        var toggleWidth = $("#toggle").width() == 300 ? "200px" : "300px";
        $('#toggle').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
    });
});
```

I just don't know how to make the inner div hide once the width gets less.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want it to hide once the animation completes, or when it begins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/3539x/)

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#toggle-button').click( function() {
        var toggleWidth = $("#toggle").width() == 300 ? 200 : 300;
        $('#toggle').animate({ width: toggleWidth + "px"});
        (toggleWidth < 240) ? $(".hide", "#toggle").hide() : $(".hide", "#toggle").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37qw8/1/)

To hide/show during animation, you can use the `step` callback method

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#toggle-button').click(function () {
        var toggleWidth = $("#toggle").width() == 300 ? "200px" : "300px";
        $('#toggle').animate({
            width: toggleWidth
        }, {
            step: function (currentWidth) {
                $(this).find('.hide').toggle(currentWidth<240?false:true);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the toogle div with:

```
$("#toggle").hide();
```

you can use animation too:

```
 $("#toggle").hide(1000);
```

is this that you want?